# Broken ADOB connection between Excel and Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to open a connection between Excel and Access database through VBA:

```
Sub get_column_real()

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim i As Long
Dim fld As Object

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=O:\MAP\05_Reporting\2018_MAPDB_NewServer.accdb;" & _
    "User Id=admin;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123456" & _
    "Jet OLEDB:System Database=C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw"
'    cn.Properties("Jet OLEDB:System database") = _
'         "C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw"
strSql = "SELECT dbo_TaskList.Id, dbo_TaskList.UserName FROM dbo_TaskList;"
cn.Open strConnection
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

End sub
```

I get:

> Runt-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)': Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

on line `cn.Open strConnection`.

According to this page: http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/80040e21.asp, I might be having some unsupported property. I am not sure which one that might be however. I have for example tried just `Password` instead of `Jet OLEDB:Database Password`, but then I get `Not a valid account name or password` error.

How do I fix the connection?

Comment: `Jet OLEDB:` not sure on the placement of this in your connection string.  Try www.connectionstrings.com  Should be like `User Id=admin;Database Password=123456` I think

Comment: Is the line break between: 
"Jet OLEDB:System 
 Database"
doing anything

Comment: Can you remove the password and the admin and try something like this: `strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & "Data source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SomeDB.mdb;"` It was working for me [some time ago](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-export-from-ms-access-to-ms-excel/)

Comment: At the very least, you're missing a semicolon after the password.

Comment: Nathan: If I do as you say, I get 'Cannot start your application. The workgroupo information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user'.  Vityata: I will look into your link, but I can't remove the password, this is at work...

Comment: Ding, ding, ding, ding! @Rory is the winner! Take the line continuation off the end of the `"User Id=` line and see what you get. Hint: a really long password (_that's good_) but you lose everything else.

Comment: @Rory; If I add the semicolon , I get `Not a valid account name or password`

Comment: Regardless, you still need the semicolon. The combination of a user id and a database password seems odd to me. I would expect a user id and user password, or a database password.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comments, you don't have an encrypted database at all, and thus shouldn't provide a password:

```
 Sub get_column_real()

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim i As Long
Dim fld As Object

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=O:\MAP\05_Reporting\2018_MAPDB_NewServer.accdb;" & _
    "User Id=admin;Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";" & _
    "Jet OLEDB:System Database=C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw"
'    cn.Properties("Jet OLEDB:System database") = _
'         "C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw"
strSql = "SELECT dbo_TaskList.Id, dbo_TaskList.UserName FROM dbo_TaskList;"
cn.Open strConnection
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

End sub
```

Querying linked tables over an OLEDB connection, however, is unsupported and won't work. You should query the linked table directly.

I strongly recommend omitting the system database, as this path will not be valid for other users and it's not applicable to accdb files anyway.

For reference, you can use `Debug.Print CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString` to get the current connection string Access is using.

Comment: Is this a connection to another datasource from within access?

Comment: Are you querying a linked table on SQL server through an OLEDB connection to Access? If so, that's not supported. Cut out the middle man and create a connection to SQL server instead.

Comment: @Erik: I tried your answer, but I still get "Not a valid account name or password" on the `.Open` line. I double-checked that user ID and password are OK, and they work fine if I open the database file manually. Also, I am running the code from within Excel VBA.

Comment: What do you mean they work when opening manually? Do you get a prompt for a password? Because if so, that likely is an ODBC prompt and you're doing something that's entirely unsupported (this code is for encrypted accdb files, and those don't have a user ID).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean, I get a prompt for user and password

Comment: If the database is "unsecured", you don't need to specify a `System Database` at all, so you can get rid of it as well as the `Jet OLEDB:Database Password` param

Comment: It's explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax